# How to get a reference to component at specific x,y coordinates on screen

Tags: react-native

I need to get a list of components (x, y) at specified coordinates, preferably in order from children to grandparents. Would be awesome if absolutely positioned components were taken into account.

Think: which components (and in what order) **would** have the opportunity to react to a click/touch event at (x, y).

I am currently trying to build a mechanism that would keep track of every component that exists, and what are it's relations to other components (which one is parent, which one is children, so I can sort them). It's ugly, lots of edgecases, components that I wish were trackable need to know about it and cooperate, and I think I'm just reimplementing something that's already there.

EDIT: This is (probably) not about measuring. It's about asking "what components are currently rendered under pixel (123,456)"

Answer (score 0):

[measure](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#measurecallback) is react native default method for any component to get update on it.

Below is the example which help you to get x and y coordinate:

```
class screenname extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <View ref={view => { this.screenname = view; }} />
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // Print component dimensions to console
        this.screenname.measure( (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
            console.log('Component width is: ' + width)
            console.log('Component height is: ' + height)
            console.log('X : ' + fx)
            console.log('Y : ' + fy)
            console.log('X offset to page: ' + px)
            console.log('Y offset to page: ' + py)
        })        
    }
}
```

Comment: I know about `measure` and `onLayout` etc. They are useful when I want to get coords of component that just mounted or re-rendered. I need something opposite: what are the components at coordinates (x, y)

Answer (score 0):

To find position of children with respect to parent what you have to do is pass parent reference to measureLayout function like below:-

```
import {findNodeHandle} from 'react-native';

calculateDimensions(){
 const handler = findNodeHandle(this.rootRef);
 this.childRef.measureLayout(handler, ( X_Position, Y_Position, Width, Height ) =>
 {
            this.setState({ 

              X_Dimension : X_Position,

              Y_Dimension: Y_Position,

              Child_View_Height: Height, 

              Child_View_Width: Width 

            });
  });
}

//Parent with nested child
<View ref={(ref) => this.rootRef = ref}>
 <View ref={(ref) => this.childRef = ref}>
 </View>
</View>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: This is very similar to @Nirmalsinh 's answer, but still not an answer to my problem. All I have is the coordinate: (x, y). I want to know what components can I find under that pixel of my screen. I could manually keep track of who-is-whose parent, an where are everybody's surfaces and dimensions and margins, and who is positioned absolutely, and who has a greater zIndex... basically reimplement in JS what react-native does already to find out who should receive a touch event... I'm asking if I really have to keep implementing this, or is there a function `getListOfComponentRefsAtCoords(x, y)`